# Add column to database in Yii

Tags: php, database, yii

Hey I'm new to Yii framework.

My question here is how to add a column to a table within a database?

I've used `addColumn()` as follows:

`Yii:app()->databasename->tablename->addColumn('tablename', 'newcolumn');`

My problem here is what do I have to use to replace `app()`. By that I mean, should app() be replaced by database name, tablename, columnname or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to add columns at run-time? Why not engineer your schema upfront? What is the initial task you are solving? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should call the function:

```
$success = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
               ->addColumn(string $table, string $column, string $type);
```

Simply replace the three variables in the `addColumn` method.

API: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#addColumn-detail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you have found the Yii::app()->dbName->tableName->addColumn() from, but as far as I know, that piece of code will not work.

First of all, if you are trying to write something that will keep your table up-to-date (E.G. a way of versioning the database by adding/dropping columns/tables), consider using [database migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration).

If you need this query for something else, you can use [CDbCommand::addColumn()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#addColumn-detail). For example:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->addColumn('user', 'name', 'varchar(64)');
```

Comment: As general practice, what is recommended? Database Migrations or the query? In the code I'm writing, I'll be creating this column once but adding values to the column when and if needed. For example, I create the column today, but will add values in the column only once every 2-3 days.

Comment: If you and other developers are working on a project and you need a way to keep everyone's database up-to-date, or if you want to later on have a build process (using Phing, for example), then migrations are better. However, if this column is created dynamically based on some logic in your code, then it's better to use the function instead. However, in the latter case, I'd urge you to reconsider your design; there is probably a much cleaner way to do this (I.E. adding columns based on some logic in your code dynamically is not really a good practice).